# transformPointCloud without PCL

Tags: pcl, pointcloud, pcl-ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there a direct analogue to [transformPointCloud](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/pcl_ros/html/namespacepcl__ros.html#a29cf585a248dc53517834f4c5a1c4d69) that doesn't use PCL but has the same form? i.e.

`transformPointCloud(frame, pointcloud2, pointcloud2b, tf)`

I am aware of the [doTransform](https://github.com/ros/geometry_experimental/blob/indigo-devel/tf2_sensor_msgs/include/tf2_sensor_msgs/tf2_sensor_msgs.h#L59) function in tf2_sensor_msgs but it is not quite the same.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/212383/transformpointcloud-without-pcl/) by [David Lu](https://answers.ros.org/users/19/david-lu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10932 on 2015-06-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That is exactly what tf2 is doing  with the transform function of the BufferInterface: http://docs.ros.org/jade/api/tf2_ros/html/c++/classtf2__ros_1_1BufferInterface.html

tf2_sensor_msgs is just a package that enables tf2 to transform sensor_msgs (including PointCloud2)

---

Originally posted by [Vincent Rabaud](https://answers.ros.org/users/358/vincent-rabaud/) with karma: 1111 on 2015-06-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0